# Serving Tomcat under a sub-URI

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I have a lot of services attached to a single domain, so I was hoping to serve Tomcat under, say, http://server_name/tomcat, with Nginx as a reverse proxy to Tomcat's HTTP connector.

The Nginx configuration is as simple as it gets:

```
location /tomcat {
   include proxy_pass.conf;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

If I leave it as it is, Tomcat is unable to resolve requests that begin with `/tomcat`, but if I otherwise set `alias /;` in Nginx, then Tomcat works just fine, but unfortunately it can't resolve the path under which it is being served, so all of the URLs are missing `/tomcat`.

I've went through the [configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html) for Tomcat 7 several times over, but I couldn't find anything that would allow me to configure Tomcat to serve all the applications under the `/tomcat` path, or otherwise add it as a prefix to the context path for every application.

I could manually configure `server.xml` with a `<context/>` container for every single app, but that'd just make me feel uneasy. Could anyone please tell me what is it that I'm obviously missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do the same thing on a several occasions in the past 4-5 years and I tried many different ways but I failed miserably on all attempts. Finally, I came to a conclusion that (a) it is not possible (b) even if by some means this can be done it would not worth the effort. Although, I would be pleasantly surprised if someone has figured this out.

Comment: How disappointing :/! I've searched far and wide and it all seems to indicate that your absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but your best bet would be to load a Java Bridge into APACHE2/PHP so that it runs java code when it encounters it.

http://www.dsl.uow.edu.au/~sk33/php5java.htm

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Tomcat 6 introduced a mechanism to achieve this, by prefixing the webapp folder or .war filename with that prefix, separated by a hash. So, e.g.:

```
${catalina.base}/webapps/tomcat#app1
${catalina.base}/webapps/tomcat#app2.war
```

...would make both accessible via http://localhost:8080/tomcat/app1/ and http://localhost:8080/tomcat/app2/, respectively, without any further configuration.

It is explained somewhat cryptically in the Tomcat [Context Container reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming), but see [this helpful message](http://markmail.org/message/p6xwms4d3dk32nya) on the Tomcat-users mailing list.

**Unfortunately**, there's a catch: apparently, Cocoon (up to 2.1.11) chokes on webapps whose paths contain a hash (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COCOON-2270).

So, when you don't have any Cocoon-based webapps running inside Tomcat, adding the 'hashed' prefix to their folder name seems like a possible solution.